# Proper use of the word "argumentation"

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Is it proper English to say "I do not understand your argumentation"?
The speaker is referring to the way arguments are presented.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please state why you think it might not be proper English. Furthermore, have you checked a dictionary? Otherwise proofreading is off-topic for this site as are questions without prior research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "argumentation" being a noun, it is indeed proper English to say *"I do not understand your [insert noun]."*

If this is in the context of a discussion about the process of reasoning or forming arguments, then it is absolutely correct.

If the speaker means to refer to the argument itself, rather than the process by which it is formed, then this would not be correct.